# Is it possible to send an Object's Method to a Function?

Tags: c#, .net, function, methods

I am wondering if it is possible (and what the syntax would be) to send an object's method to a function.

Example:

```
Object "myObject" has two methods "method1" and "method2"
```

I would like to have a function along the lines of:

```
public bool myFunc(var methodOnObject)
{
   [code here]
   var returnVal = [run methodOnObject here]
   [code here]
   return returnVal;
}
```

So that in another function I could do something like

```
public void overallFunction()
{
   var myObject = new ObjectItem();
   var method1Success = myFunc(myObject.method1);
   var method2Success = myFunc(myObject.method2);
}
```

Comment: Delgates should solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there really a need for explicit delegates? Maybe this approach would help you:

```
private class MyObject
{
    public bool Method1() { return true; } // Your own logic here
    public bool Method2() { return false; } // Your own logic here
}

private static bool MyFunction(Func<bool> methodOnObject)
{
    bool returnValue = methodOnObject();
    return returnValue;
}    

private static void OverallFunction()
{
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    bool method1Success = MyFunction(myObject.Method1);
    bool method2Success = MyFunction(myObject.Method2);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that is a typo... `Func<...>` very much **is** a `delegate`.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment, it was about "Is there really a need for delegates?" and making an example with Func which is a delegate...

Comment: That is great, thanks.  I accepted this as the answer as it used my example directly.

Comment: Marc Garvell: I meant explicitly using the keyword delegate. Using a Func<...> is more comprehendable and nice syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you need to use a delegate. Delegates are fairly analogous to function pointers in C/C++.

You'll first need to declare the signature of the delegate. Say I have this function:

```
private int DoSomething(string data)
{
    return -1;
}
```

The delegate declaration would be...

```
public delegate int MyDelegate(string data);
```

You could then declare myFunc in this way..

```
public bool myFunc(MyDelegate methodOnObject)
{
    [code here]
    int returnValue = methodOnObject("foo");
    [code here]
    return returnValue;
}
```

You can then call it in one of two ways:

```
myFunc(new MyDelegate(DoSomething));
```

Or, in C# 3.0 and later, you can use the shorthand of...

```
myFunc(DoSomething);
```

(It just wraps the provided function in the default constructor for that delegate automatically. The calls are functionally identical).

If you don't care to actually create a delegate or actual function implementation for simple expressions, the following will work in C# 3.0 as well:

```
public bool myFunc(Func<string, int> expr)
{
    [code here]
    int returnValue = methodOnObject("foo");
    [code here]
    return returnValue;
}
```

Which could then be called like so:

```
myFunc(s => return -1);
```

Comment: C# 3.5 also lets you avoid declaring your own delegate type, as you can do `Func<string, int>` which represents the same signature as your `MyDelegate` type.

Comment: @Simon: In some cases, yes, there are some built-in delegate types, and 3.5 did add several potentially useful ones as part of the LINQ support package. That being said, being able to declare a delegate is something that, IMO, any .NET developer should be able to do.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for all the information and details.  Voted up, but used other as offical answer as it directly used my example.  Sometimes wish there could be 2 accepted answers as combined your two answers give all the details anyone could want for this question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using delegates ..

Here is an example..

```
delegate string myDel(int s);
public class Program
{
    static string Func(myDel f)
    {
        return f(2);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Test obj = new Test();
        myDel d = obj.func;
        Console.WriteLine(Func(d));
    }
}
class Test
{
    public string func(int s)
    {
        return s.ToString();
    }
}
```